# Mapping DiskDrive to Storage Controllers

Tags: windows, command-line, device-manager, devcon

I have a task to gather information regarding the storage controller on which the disk drive is present for verification purpose. After some research, all I can find is use of devcon tool to gather necessary information.

I can get storage controller details using following commands

```
devcon drivernodes =SCSIAdapter
devcon drivernodes =hdc
```

These commands display information regarding the  position of the controller. I can similarly gather information regarding the disk drives

```
devcon drivernodes =DiskDrive
```

But I cannot find a mapping between these 2. I have many drives and many controllers on servers and finding it hard to gather the mapping using either a command-line or programmable way.

But I did find the mapping detail using gui "Device Manager" and select the particular disk drive and then scrolling to a property "parent" that shows the  info of the controller gathered before.

[image]

does anyone know how to get this parent property using command line on windwos ?

Answer (score 3):

Try in powershell.

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-wmiobject -class Win32_SCSIControllerDevice